# Is there some point where the minor edit limit is lifted?

Tags: support, edits

I'm currently a >20K user, with the [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399) badge on Super User (in short, I don't actually have any reason to edit, other than an error of some sort *bugging me*). I just did a one character edit (bad geek, no cookie) on [a post](https://superuser.com/posts/503739/revisions) - primarily because I recall this happening before.

As I understand it, this *is* a minor edit and should have been automatically rejected. It's however an accepted edit.

Did the edit get counted as a legitimate 7-8 character edit, or is there something else at play here?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Once you go past 2k, your edits no longer need approval.

Comment: I recall there was a mechanism that automatically rejected minor edits. I'm not talking about approval here. Amusingly you just did a one charecter edit, which is exactly what I'm talking about

Comment: I don't recall such mechanism ever being in place for anyone with edit privileges (>= 2k)

Comment: Single character **suggested** edits are not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get Editing privileges, there's no restriction on what kind of edits you can do. You can do a substantial edit or a trivial edit, there's no restriction.

The assumption is that by now, you've edited enough that the system trusts you not to do trivial edits, or if required, they no longer need to be approved