# How could this user edit only one character?

Tags: discussion, edits

Someone [edited a typo](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/11133/2) in one of my posts.

Much appreciated, but it was just deleting one character. How could he do that? I thought there was a minimum of 6 characters for an edit to go through? (A rather silly rule if I may say so, but how did the user bypass the rule?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He didn't bypass any rule, since 2K users can edit a post without character count restrictions. Those only apply to < 2K users from which *suggested* edits end up in the review queue.

You can read this in [the edit privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: (I could not find the duplicate, but I am pretty sure there is. So if you find it, please VtC)

Comment: Would this post work as a dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155261/is-there-some-point-where-the-minor-edit-limit-is-lifted

Comment: @AzizShaikh IMO, yes.

Comment: Okay, then we close it as a duplicate.